# Gmail contact import

Tags: c#, exception, gmail, google-contacts-api

Importing contact from gmail in c# is not working ....giving exception as 
"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/fullMovedPermanently" ...
 Gmail has changed protocol from http to https since 31st march 14.
I was  using way of using client libraries to get contacts earlier ,But i am not able to get corresponding client library which is having this https.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Haresh,I have the same problem.Did you find any solution?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google_Data_API_Setup_2.2.0.0.msi  

I downloaded this library ,which has https as protocol in it ...this Data Api has required google contact libraries in it.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
http://%22http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/fullMovedPermanently%22
```

to

```
 https://%22http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/fullMovedPermanently%22
```

HTTP stands for Hypertext Transfer Protocol. It's the first element you see in any URL and

you can think of it as the language used to deliver information over the web. Most web

browsers (including Internet Explorer) use an encrypted protocol called Secure Sockets

Layer (SSL) to access secure webpages. These pages use the prefix HTTPS. The "s" stands for secure.

Comment: Hey ,  I am using client library so i can't do this change manually ,i want library which has this in it ...@HackerMan